# Highlight duplicates of matching data from two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a formula or a way to highlight if there are duplicates of matches from two columns. 

Ex:

```
A1=Green B1= Pen
A2=Red   B2= Pen
A3=Green B3= Pen
A4=Green B4= Binder
```

In this case, I would want row 1 & 3 to be highlighted. 

I feel like this can be simple, but for the life of me, I can't figure it out. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose columns A and B, Add a formula conditional formatting using this formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1)>1
```

[image]